# nested templates (template template parameters)

Tags: c++, templates

How to write a template function that accepts nested templates?

For example, I'd like to write following function:

```
void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container);
```

Had tried:

```
template<
  template<typename> class T1,
  template<typename> class T2,
  class T3
>
void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container) {
  for (auto &e : container)
    for (auto x : e)
      std::cout<<e<<' ';
  std::cout<<'\n';
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::deque<int>> c = {{1,2},{3}};
  print(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile error from g++:

```
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:23:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(std::vector<std::deque<int> >&)’
       print(c);
              ^
a.cc:12:10: note: candidate: template<template<class> class T1, template<class> class T2, class T3> void print(const T1<T2<T3> >&)
     void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container) {
          ^
a.cc:12:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cc:23:14: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
       print(c);
              ^
a.cc:8:32: note: provided for ‘template<class> class T1’
       template<typename> class T1,
                                ^
```

Compile error from Clang:

```
a.cc:23:7: error: no matching function for call to 'print'
      print(c);
      ^~~~~
a.cc:12:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding
      template template parameter
    void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container) {
         ^
```

Also tried:

```
template<
  template<template<typename> class> class T1,
  template<typename> class T2,
  class T3
>
void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container);
```

but it still has compile error even before deduction:

```
a.cc:12:25: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
    void print(const T1<T2<T3>> &container) {
                        ^
```

---- EDIT ----

What if I'd like to return a pointer to one of it's type?

```
 T3 get(const T1<T2<T3>> &container);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested C++ template parameters for functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373466/nested-c-template-parameters-for-functions)

Comment: Yeah, that one looks like a fair duplicate. I'd recommend just having a single template parameter rather than going to all of this hassle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though, I'll prefer you use a single template and pick the typedefs from it.

Something like:

```
template<typename T1>
void print(const T1& container) { //As opposed to const T1<T2<T3>> &container
    using T2 = typename T1::value_type;
    using T3 = typename T2::value_type;

  for (auto &e : container)
    for (auto x : e)
      std::cout<<x<<' ';
  std::cout<<'\n';
}
```

But if you must go your way, then this will work *([`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) are actually declared with two template parameters, though the allocator is defaulted)*:

```
template<
  template<typename, typename> class T1,
  template<typename, typename> class T2,
  typename AllocT1, typename AllocT2, 
  typename T3
>
void print(const T1<T2<T3, AllocT2>, AllocT1> &container) {
  for (auto &e : container)
    for (auto x : e)
      std::cout<<x<<' ';
  std::cout<<'\n';
}
```

But there is a neater solution:

```
template<typename T1, 
         typename T2 = typename T1::value_type,
         typename T3 = typename T2::value_type>
T3 print(const T1& container){

  for (auto &e : container)
    for (auto x : e)
      std::cout<<x<<' ';
  std::cout<<'\n';

  return T3();
}
```

The choice is expressly yours. :-)

**EDIT:**

> What if I'd like to return a pointer to one of it's type?
>
> ```
> T3 get(const T1<T2<T3>> &container);
> ```

In C++14, you can simply use an `auto` placeholder return type, or use the latter solution above.

Comment: I would use `Args1...` for `typename...` or `typename` for `Alloc1`.

Comment: @Jarod42, Yea, since its only one more template arg... Makes sense. Thanks Jarod. Improved!

Comment: I'd prefer first one, but actually I'd need to use one of the type as return value, e.g. `T3 get(const T1<T2<T3>> &container);`  Do you know how to write it like that?

Comment: @Deqing, Please see (the 3rd code snippet in) my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A single template parameter will work for you:

```
template<class T>
void print(const T& container) {
  for (auto &e : container)
    for (auto x : e) std::cout << x << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0698113c5cbc7a0b)

Comment: maybe add some checks to make the error messages a bit more clear(some static asserts).