# How to work with template which are template parameter

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to make a double list of some type. In this case it is double list of "BoardCell".
Here is my implementation for List:

```
template<typename T, typename... TT>
struct List {
    typedef T head;
    typedef List<TT...> next;
    constexpr static int size = 1 + next::size;
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T> {
    typedef T head;
    constexpr static int size = 1;
};
```

And here is the implementation for BoardCell:(when "CellType" and "Direction" are enums)

```
template<CellType CT, Direction D, int L>
struct BoardCell {
    constexpr static CellType type = CT;
    constexpr static Direction direction = D;
    constexpr static int length = L;
};
```

now im trying to make the GameBoard.
This is my trying, and I cant find why it is not working:

```
template<template<template<template<CellType C, Direction D, int L> class BoardCell> class List> class List>
struct GameBoard {
    typedef List<List<BoardCell<C, D, L>>> board;
};
```

(Yes, this is x3 nested template :(   )
I believe the line of the template is good, and the typedef of the board is the problem in here.

Edit- ADDITION:
Here is an example for GameBoard input:

```
typedef​ ​GameBoard​<​List​<​ ​List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>>,
                        List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​X​,​ RIGHT​,​ ​1​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​A​,​ UP​,​ ​1​>>,
                        List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>>>>​ gameBoard​;
```

I do not use std::tuple because this is a part of Homework and we need to implement also the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested C++ template parameters for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373466/nested-c-template-parameters-for-functions)

Comment: Are you sure you have homework to write a linked list of *types*, and not a linked list of *values*, templated over the value type?

Comment: Yes, this is a meta programming task, all the calculations should run on compile time.
@Caleth

Comment: You are defining a template class that takes a template mess, and giving it a *type*, which so happens to be an instantiation of some template. What is `GameBoard<...>::board` intended to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoardCell` in `GameBoard` is entirely unrelated to the `BoardCell` template, ditto the *two* `List`s.

There isn't anything you have defined of kind

```
template<template<template<CellType, Direction, int> class> class> class
```

with which you can pass to your definition of `GameBoard`. Most likely, you should be passing a *specific instantiation* of your `List` template, such as

```
List​<​ ​List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>>,
      List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​X​,​ RIGHT​,​ ​1​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​A​,​ UP​,​ ​1​>>,
      List​<​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>,​ ​BoardCell​<​EMPTY​,​ UP​,​ ​0​>>>
```

But then you have a do-nothing definition

```
template<typename Board>
struct GameBoard {
    typedef Board board;
};
```

Comment: Ty for helping, i made an edit to the question.
Can't use std::tuple because this is an homework.
and i added an example for input.